# Перестала работать прокрутка в Chrome и Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, webbrowser

На страничке должна работать плавная прокрутка по странице при клике на определенный пункт меню. Реализовано с помощью smoothscroll.js и работало до недавнего времени во всех браузерах. Теперь только в Firefox. Может кто-то сказать в чем причина и как ее исправить?

[Ссылка на страницу](http://mass.16mb.com)

Спасибо!

Comment: Вспомни чего ты сделал до `недавнего времени`  попытайся определить от чего может быть....

Comment: Да в том и дело, что куски брал из одного шаблона. И в том шаблоне тоже перестало работать, хотя там с самого начала ничего не менялось. Что-то явно связано с работой браузеров.